# Setting a private attribute which is an array on a PHP class fails

Tags: php, object

I have a problem while setting a private attribute on a PHP class, my __set() method is being called however when I perform this on an attribute which is an array it performs first my __get() method which renders the ser unusable :/

```
$this->person['name'] = 'perro';
```

simply, doesn't work,any idea on this subject ?

Comment: Can you show the __set() method?

Comment: Could you show a bit more code ? Like a small test-case the reproduces the problem ? Also make sure your error_reporting level is so E_NOTICE errors are showed (this might really help you on this one) ; and, finally, are you sure the "person" property exists in your class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your attribute is **private**, not being able to see it *(either for reading nor writing)* from a sub-class if perfectly normal : `private` means you attribute is **private** to the class it is defined in.

That's the difference between private and protected :

- private = accessible only for the one class it's declared in
- protected = accessible from any class that "is a" class of the type you'r declaring (super or sub-class)
- public = accessible from anyone

For more informations about this in PHP, see [Visibilty](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in the manual.

You will probably find more information on the net about that, if necessary : it's one of the basics of Object-Oriented programming, and is true in other languages *(like C++, for instance)*

Search for keywords like "Visibility", "Encapsulation", or "Information Hiding", for instance -- in relation with OOP / Object-Oriented Programmation

Answer (score 0):

Solve it, the problem was I was trying to set a private variable within my class and I don't understand why if Im exteing PHP doesn't let me touch this attributes

to correct this problem I just changed my attributes from private to protected

Comment: That's the definition of a private property. Only the class defining the private attribute may alter/access its contents. A protected attribute allows child classes to alter/access it. 

Just saw that Pascal MARTIN explained this difference nicely.